# Android - How to make Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) work with singleInstance Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity that I've marked with `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.  It's marked as `singleInstance` because I want to be able to share data to my app from other apps, without opening up a second instance of the app.  It's important that I only have once instance running because the app interfaces with hardware (drone controller) and you can only connect from one instance.

But I also want to be able to access local videos from this app.  To do that, I have the following in my `onCreate()` function:

```
        val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                (result.data?.data as Uri).let { uri ->
                    ... // Do stuff to video...
                }
            } else if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                showToast("Video Selection cancelled")
            }
        }
        mChooserBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.setType("video/*")
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
```

The problem is that now, even after selecting a video, the result code is always `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`, and `result.data==null`.

If I change the line in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, I can select videos, BUT then when I share data from another app, I end up with two instances of my app open, which is NOT what I want.

**Question is: How can I ensure that my app just has a single instance open, AND be able to select videos from my app?**

Comment: "when I share data from another app, I end up with two instances of my app open" -- no, you do not. You have two instances of your *activity* open. "It's important that I only have once instance running because the app interfaces with hardware" -- IMHO, there should be zero lines of code in an activity that involves interfacing with hardware. That should be handled by something else, such as a singleton. And, if you do that, then it will not matter whether you wind up with extra instances of an activity, because you will only have one instance of the singleton in your process.

Answer (score 1):

It that `android:launchMode="singleTask"` solves the problem

Comment: took a lot of search to know this issue is related to singleInstance. changed to singleTask and it worked. +1